# pip is giving an error and i can't find an explanation

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm on windows, and pip was working just fine, but now it's giving this error message, unclear what changed.
"Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python.exe"  "C:\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Have you changed the location of pip or python? Or have you reinstalled python? Or uninstalled any version of python?

Comment: Have you checked if file is present in C:\Scrips\pip.exe

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your system is not able to find 'c:\python.exe', try looking at this location if the file is present.

1. Try creating environment variables by name "python" which runs your python executable present at 'c:\python.exe'

Easy way if you struggle in step 1

2. Re-install python and add path of python